# Retrieve a substring from text in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file with the below contents.

[image]

I want to be able to generate a .csv that includes a column to display the giraffe<4 digit number> when that pattern is available in the "text" column.

So far I have written the below code which does not compute the slice start and end indexes dynamically/for each row, for Giraffe_numbers.

```py
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'test.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
sub = "giraffe"
# column to identify if Giraffe is present
data['Giraffe_Present'] = data['text'].str.contains(sub)
# column to identify index of Giraffe in text
data["Giraffe_Index"] = data['text'].str.find(sub)
# column to identify starting position for slice
data['Giraffe_start'] = data['Giraffe_Index'].apply(lambda row: row)
# column to identify ending position for slice
data['Giraffe_end'] = data['Giraffe_Index'].apply(lambda row: row+11)
# column to store sliced Giraffe number from text
data['Giraffe_numbers'] = data['text'].apply(lambda row: row[data['Giraffe_Index'].apply(lambda row: row).max():data['Giraffe_Index'].apply(lambda row: row+11).max()])
print(data)
```

This is the output. The results are skewed for #2,#4 and #5 as Giraffe_numbers uses the start and end indexes corresponding to #1.

[image]

Comment: "Thoughts?" is not a good question on this platform. I tried thinking of a better question for a good 5-10 minutes after looking over your post. I edited with my best guess of what you are trying to ask. Be sure to be more specific in future posts. You'll find it more productive in both your own reasoning/thought process and you'll notice more quality answers and question interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using multiple steps why not do everything in one go?

```py
data['Giraffe_numbers'] = data.apply(
    lambda row: row['text'][
        row["text"].find('giraffe') : row['text'].find('giraffe') + 11
    ]
    if row['text'].find('giraffe') > 0
    else '',
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: great, thanks! the multiple steps were part of debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you expect but It could be interesting

Input data:

```
>>> df
                     text
0      myname giraffe0086
1           cat whale4321
2             giraffe9064
3     poultry dolphin4356
4  fifty giraffe2345 nine
5      giraffe3434 catnap
6        nothing to catch
```

Find animals and numbers into string:

```
import re

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-15
PAT = re.compile(r'(?P<animal>\w+)(?=(?P<number>\d{4}))')

sre = df['text'].apply(PAT.search)
```

```
>>> sre
0    <re.Match object; span=(7, 14), match='giraffe'>
1       <re.Match object; span=(4, 9), match='whale'>
2     <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='giraffe'>
3    <re.Match object; span=(8, 15), match='dolphin'>
4    <re.Match object; span=(6, 13), match='giraffe'>
5     <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='giraffe'>
6                                                None
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Build your a dataframe with `animal`, `start`, `end` and `number` columns:

```
extract_data = lambda r: (r.group('animal'), r.start(), r.end()-4, r.group('number')

df1 = sre[sre.notnull()].apply(extract_data).apply(pd.Series) \
                        .rename(columns={0: 'animal', 1: 'start', 2: 'end', 3: 'number'})
```

Merge `df` and `df1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis="columns")
```

```
>>> df
                     text   animal  start   end number
0      myname giraffe0086  giraffe    7.0  14.0   0086
1           cat whale4321    whale    4.0   9.0   4321
2             giraffe9064  giraffe    0.0   7.0   9064
3     poultry dolphin4356  dolphin    8.0  15.0   4356
4  fifty giraffe2345 nine  giraffe    6.0  13.0   2345
5      giraffe3434 catnap  giraffe    0.0   7.0   3434
6        nothing to catch      NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
```